# Is there a way for reading key value on many lines from a file?

Tags: c, linux, glibc, glib

I have the following config file:

```
 [GENERAL_CONFIG]
    filter_subnetworks = 192.168.105.0/24 1.1.0.0/16 192.168.105.0/24
    192.168.105.0/24 1.1.0.0/16 192.168.105.0/24 
    192.168.105.0/24 1.1.0.0/16 192.168.105.0/24
```

and i want to read all subnetworks with `g_key_file_get_string_list (gkf, "GENERAL_CONFIG", "filter_subnetworks", &s_len, &error)` but this function read one single line.

Comment: Seems like an .ini style configuration. You could try iniparser: https://github.com/ndevilla/iniparser

Comment: Yes but i need to use glib library on linux os.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your input file doesn't comply with the formatting required by the [glib Key-value file parser](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Key-value-file-parser.html) functions.

All key values should be on a single line, and you should have an explicit list separator character (not just space) such as `;` or `,`, see the [`g_key_file_set_list_separator()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Key-value-file-parser.html#g-key-file-set-list-separator) function.

Convert the file to comply with the required glib format if you're going to use their API. Note that as soon as you save your file back out, it *will* use the glib API, so there's little point in "tricking" it to load something else.